# Java regular expressions lower upper case

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem using regular expressions I should try these:

```
"<td><font size=1>LA SPEDIZIONE E' IN VIAGGIO</font></td>
<td><font size=1>Hub Pacchi Milano</font></td>"
```

First I should try that with uppercase and then the one with lower and upper case.
I stopped here:

```
Pattern uppercase= Pattern.compile("<td><font size=1>(.*?)</font></td>"); 
Pattern lowcase = Pattern.compile("<td><font size=1>(.*?)</font></td>");
```

But this I look for everything! how can I do?

Comment: DO NOT PARSE HTML WITH REGULAR EXPRESSIONS! See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Answer (score 0):

Though I strongly recommend using a decent HTML parser to extract this information, to unblock you with case-insensitive way of using the pattern, you could use the following:

```
String str =
    "<td><font size=1>LA SPEDIZIONE E' IN VIAGGIO</font></td><td><font size=1>Hub Pacchi Milano</font></td>";
Pattern uppercase = Pattern.compile("<td><font size=1>(.*?)</font></td>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = uppercase.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
LA SPEDIZIONE E' IN VIAGGIO
Hub Pacchi Milano
```

Comment: The problem is that in addition to those I also tag html: "<td><font size=1>29-03-2012</font></td> <td><font size=1>16:41</font></td>" therefore, this method returns me everything!

Comment: Why would this method return you everything if you are using group(1)? group(0) would return you the <td>...</td>, right?

Comment: DO NOT PARSE HTML WITH REGULAR EXPRESSIONS! See codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: @JimGarrison, I completely agree and strongly oppose using regex for parsing HTML and I mentioned the same in the response.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you explain how to use group (1), .. ?

Comment: group(0) contains the entire portion of the input that matched your regex. In case your regex has groups defined used `()`, then each group from left right is numbered from `1`. Thus, anything that matches your group `(.*?)` will be returned by group (1).